# Sudo su doesn't work on Microsoft Azure

Tags: 16.04, sudo, root, azure

I am going to write `sudo su` on terminal but I get this error.

```
sudo: unknown user: root  
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 running on a virtual machine in the Microsoft Azure cloud. I can't login as root.

Comment: What is "microsoft azure Ubuntu 16.04"?

Comment: File a support request. This should work on a default Ubuntu installation, so this is a problem with your service provider

Comment: I use microsoft azure . My machine is ubuntu 16.04 cloud server

Comment: What do you get when you run `sudo su` without the dash "-"?

Comment: No evidence that it was ever run with the dash. The root account is disabled in Ubuntu too, but `sudo su` works as muru pointed out. Problem is specific to the service.

Answer (score 5):

"By default, the root user is disabled on Linux virtual machines in Azure. ", see more on 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-use-root-privileges

You might be able to use `sudo <cmd>` one command at a time ... if this doesn't work you will have to contact Microsoft support, I think.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the root user mode is disabled, since **`root/superuser`** mode allows anything to be done, even if its malicious. This is also to discourage hackers or automated scripts that try to manipulate the root permissions.

Quoting [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-use-root-privileges) on Microsoft Docs:

> By default, the root user is disabled on Linux virtual machines in
>   Azure. Users can run commands with elevated privileges by using the
>   sudo command. However, the experience may vary depending on how the
>   system was provisioned.
>
> 1. SSH key and password OR password only - the virtual machine was
>      provisioned with either a certificate (.CER file) or SSH key as well
>      as a password, or just a user name and password. In this case sudo
>      will prompt for the user's password before executing the command.
> 2. SSH key only - the virtual machine was provisioned with a certificate
>      (.cer, .pem, or .pub file) or SSH key, but no password. In this case
>      sudo will not prompt for the user's password before executing the
>      command.

You can visit [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-use-root-privileges) for more information:

Answer (score 0):

An alternative suggestion would be to use `sudo -i` which will run your user's shell with sudo privileges. Otherwise it may be wise to rely on the sudo timeout, which means you only have to enter your sudo password once within the defined time frame. Also worth noting is that `sudo -v` should extend the current timeout period by a further 15 minutes if you're already in a sudo session.